# Client can't connect to SignalR Hub (CORS does not work)

Tags: asp.net, signalr

My StartUp.cs in server (Implementing cross-domain requests by using Owin.UseCors):

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {
        // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
        // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
        // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
        // providing a cors options with a different policy.
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
            // EnableJSONP = true
        };
        // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
        // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
        // path.
        map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });
}
```

My client (console project):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IHubProxy _hub;
    string url = @"http://111.111.111.111:13098/signalr/hubs";
    var connection = new HubConnection(url, querystringData);
    _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");
    connection.Start().Wait();
    _hub.On("Broadcast", x => Console.WriteLine(x));
}
```

---

Only when I run the client (console.exe) at server (signalr project is hosted in IIS), can it connect to hub.

If I run the client at my computer, it it not capable of getting connected.

Why?

Input http://111.111.111.111:13098/signalr/hubs at Chrome:

[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you host SIgnalR server? Self host or IIS site? Do you have ports open in firewall?

Comment: IIS host. And already set this port in the whitelist. (I can access other web pages hosted in this project)

Comment: Use Chrome developer tools to check what network packets are sent and that should give you more insights.

Comment: No response data. Just  `GET http://111.111.111.111:12306/signalr/hubs net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: Solved. I used a wrong port... firewall blocked..

Comment: What did u do ? Could u explain pls?

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable JSONP and see?

```cs
var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { EnableJSONP = true };
```

Comment: No. I've set " EnableJSONP = true " , still get noting (connection time out)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I've used a wrong port... firewall blocked it.